# Showing ListPreference from the main activity

Tags: android, listpreference

I have a

```
SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
```

SettingsActivity is populated by addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences) where I have my custom

```
SMode extends ListPreference
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="key"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:title="Title" >

<package.SMode
    android:title="Mode"
        android:entries="@array/1"
        android:entryValues="@array/2"
    android:key="prefSMode"
                android:summary="Sum"
    />
```

What I want to do is to show this ListPreference dialog by clicking a button outside the PreferenceActivity. In other words a shortcut for setting "mode" without leaving my main acitivy and going to preferences.

I also need it to work with APII level < 11.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) see example [here](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html).
You can use it inside and `FragmentActivity` or in `DialogFragment`.
But if you need to use below API 11 consider a custom view.

Comment: Yes, I need it work with API level < 11. What you mean by custom view?

Comment: To make it look like Preferences.